# Is it possible to create line between elements in CSS3?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using jQuery Draggable in the application I create and I'm wondering if it would be possible to somehow create a line between dialog box and element on website? I want it to follow draggable box as you drag it.

I'm looking for CSS/HTML way and not jQuery/JS way. If there is no way to create it using pure CSS3/HTML5 then I'll start with JS approach - just wanted to know :)

[image]

Comment: You can't use canvas without javascript.

Comment: @dystroy Too bad but thanks for clarifying! Then I think it's my only way to get to know HTML5 canvas and create it using JS/HTML5 canvas solution.

Comment: Sure it's possible. Mouse events give you info on the cursor in real time, and canvas lets you paint corresponding lines. I recommend investing some time in a canvas tutorial.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas That's what I'll do. Thanks! I just wanted to make sure that there isn't easier HTML/CSS way to do that before I start.

Comment: Well, without *any* JavaScript you're not going to get far I'm afraid. That said, you can leverage on CSS for the dashes and rotation like this: http://jsfiddle.net/A3TN3/1/.

Answer (score 10):

Basically: **no,** there isn't a way to achieve this using CSS only.

But, if this is observed as a CSS riddle (I recommend you don't use the following solution in any real-world application whatsoever), you might be able to achieve something similar. Again, this is going to be completely abusive of both HTML and CSS.

You basically create a lot of `divs`, each stands for a 'pixel'. You change the `divs`' `background-color` on `:hover`, and maintain the `background-color` after `:hover` state is gone using a (yet another abusive) `transition` trick (pseudo-infinite delay).

Here's a demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/6zCpW/). Try hovering on the top parts to see the 'breadcrumbs' that get drawn as you move your mouse.

I, again, exaggerate this is completely abusive and shouldn't be used in any actual application.

This can be expanded to create a tiny painting program using CSS. I've made a little dabblet to illustrate: [another little link](http://dabblet.com/gist/3738326) (try drawing by clicking and moving your mouse!)

**The bottom line:** Use JavaScript -- it's the only resort in this case (you can't control a `canvas` without JavaScript).

Comment: You can use canvas for that or svg even.